# Why is SUMPRODUCT function showing a extremely small value while the correct answer is zero?

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

Thank you for reading the post.

I am trying to use the excel function "SUMPRODUCT" to calculate the sum of products of two sequences. The appeared answer is an extremely small number(2.78E-17), given that I already know the answer is zero.

I do not understand why the answer is not zero. Can anyone help me?

The two sequences are:

1. Probability Sequence: [0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.04, 0.08, 0.04], stored in B2:B16.
2. Value Sequence: [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, -2, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], stored in C2:C16.

The formula of the answer cell: =SUMPRODUCT(B2:B16, C2:C16).

The shown answer: 2.78E-17

The Correct answer: 0

The print screen of the excel file is attached below:

1. [Print screen showing the formula of the cell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52j2v.png)
2. [Print screen showing the excel spreadsheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ePYD.png)

Comment: This is a problem with converting Decimal based fractional numbers to binary encoding (as done in computers). You can use the Round() function to get rid of the extremely tiny artifacts of this process in your case: Round( (your calculation),2) should do the trick.

Comment: @RetiredGeek, I see! Thank you so much for that, the problem is solved!